# Test Google Analytics on iOS

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I want to add the ["General Campaign & Traffic Source Attribution"](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/campaigns#general-campaigns) option of Google Analytics to my iOS app.

I added the GA SDK (not the pod file):

- GAI.h
- GAIDictionaryBuilder.h
- GAIEcommerceProduct.h
- GAIEcommerceProductAction.h
- GAIEcommercePromotion.h
- GAIFields.h
- GAILogger.h
- GAITrackedViewController.h
- GAITracker.h
- CoreData.framework
- SystemConfiguration.framework
- libsqlite3.dylib
- libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a

(I did NOT add libAdIdAccess.a lib)

and added screen tracking and it works fine.

Then I added the following code ([from the attached link above](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/campaigns#general-campaigns)) to my `AppDelegate.m`

```
// For iOS 9.0 and later
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(nonnull NSURL *)url
            options:(nonnull NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options {


  NSString *urlString = [url absoluteString];

  id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithName:@"tracker"
                                                      trackingId:@"UA-XXXX-Y"];
  // provided correcrt trackingId (works for screen tracking)    

  // setCampaignParametersFromUrl: parses Google Analytics campaign ("UTM")
  // parameters from a string url into a Map that can be set on a Tracker.
  GAIDictionaryBuilder *hitParams = [[GAIDictionaryBuilder alloc] init];

  // Set campaign data on the map, not the tracker directly because it only
  // needs to be sent once.
  [hitParams setCampaignParametersFromUrl:urlString];

  // Campaign source is the only required campaign field. If previous call
  // did not set a campaign source, use the hostname as a referrer instead.
  if(![hitParams get:kGAICampaignSource] && [url host].length !=0) {
    // Set campaign data on the map, not the tracker.
    [hitParams set:@"referrer" forKey:kGAICampaignMedium];
    [hitParams set:[url host] forKey:kGAICampaignSource];
  }

  NSDictionary *hitParamsDict = [hitParams build];

  // A screen name is required for a screen view.
  //[tracker set:kGAIScreenName value:@"screen name"];

  // Previous V3 SDK versions.
  // [tracker send:[[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] setAll:hitParamsDict] build]];

  // SDK Version 3.08 and up.
  //[tracker send:[[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createScreenView] setAll:hitParamsDict] build]];
  [tracker send:hitParamsDict];

}
```

How can I test that it will work and the app will successfully send the referrer source info to GA?

Is there something similar to [this test](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/testing-play-campaigns#intro) for iOS?

One more question, just to make sure I understood correctly, 
If I'm only interested in [General Campaign & Traffic Source Attribution](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/campaigns#general-campaigns) and not [iOS install campaign measurement](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/campaigns#ios-install) then I don't need to add the `libAdIdAccess.a` lib from the sdk, check the iOS Campaign Tracking is ON or use the IDFA, correct?

Thank you

Comment: Could you find a way to test this?